# file operations aio_read changed in kernel 4.1

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, system-calls

I have a driver I maintain, I need to compile it with Linux headers 4.1.21 but
I get compile errors for `aio_read`, `aio_write`, they are missing from `struct file_operations`, I assume they were replaced.
How do i find out what the replacements are?

[`fs.h` in kernel 4.0](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h?v=4.0) has:

```
struct file_operations {
struct module *owner;
loff_t (*llseek) (struct file *, loff_t, int);
ssize_t (*read) (struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
ssize_t (*write) (struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
ssize_t (*aio_read) (struct kiocb *, const struct iovec *, unsigned long, loff_t);
ssize_t (*aio_write) (struct kiocb *, const struct iovec *, unsigned long, loff_t);
ssize_t (*read_iter) (struct kiocb *, struct iov_iter *);
ssize_t (*write_iter) (struct kiocb *, struct iov_iter *);
...
```

[`fs.h` in kernel 4.1](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h?v=4.1)   has:

```
struct file_operations {
struct module *owner;
loff_t (*llseek) (struct file *, loff_t, int);
ssize_t (*read) (struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
ssize_t (*write) (struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
ssize_t (*read_iter) (struct kiocb *, struct iov_iter *);
ssize_t (*write_iter) (struct kiocb *, struct iov_iter *);
int (*iterate) (struct file *, struct dir_context *);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing kernel work you should have a subscription to [Linux Weekly News](https://lwn.net/).

A very quick search turned up [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/636466/) which mentions that `aio_read` and `aio_write` are being handled by the `read_iter` and `write_iter`.

You can also find a brief statement to that effect in [`Documentation/filesystems/porting`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/porting.html).