# What will happen if a device driver not implemented the asyn write function?

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers

> ssize_t (*read) (struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
>
> Used to retrieve data from the device. A null pointer in this position
>   causes thereadsystem call to fail with-EINVAL(“Invalid argument”). A
>   nonnegative returnvalue  represents  the  number  of  bytes
>   successfully  read  (the  return  value  is  a “signed size” type,
>   usually the native integer type for the target platform).
>
> ssize_t (*aio_read)(struct kiocb *, char __user *, size_t,loff_t);
>
> Initiates an  asynchronous  read—a  read  operation  that  might  not
>   complete before the  function  returns.  If  this  method  isNULL, 
>   all  operations  will  be  pro-cessed (synchronously) byread instead.
>
> ssize_t (*write) (struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t
>   *);
>
> Sends data to the device. IfNULL,-EINVALis returned to the program
>   calling thewritesystem  call.  The  return  value,  if  nonnegative, 
>   represents  the  number  ofbytes successfully written.
>
> ssize_t (*aio_write)(struct kiocb *, const char __user *, size_t,
>   loff_t *);
>
> Initiates an asynchronous write operation on the device.

Took this statement from LDD3, can anyone please explain what will happen if a device driver not implemented the asyn write function? Will, it upgrades to sync silently like asyn read does (if it is NULL).

Comment: You may want to check this out: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324661/file-operations-aio-read-changed-in-kernel-4-1

Comment: @dragosht I read that link, I was not able to find the answer for my doubt in that link. am i missing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `aio_read` and `aio_write` entries in `file_operations` are obsolete](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/porting.html), replaced (albeit not identically) by `read_iter` and `write_iter`. Write-capable `file_operations` need to have at least one of `write` and/or `write_iter`, and the VFS will [use whichever one is available](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.4/source/fs/read_write.c#L490). (The availability is checked earlier, and recorded using `FMODE_CAN_WRITE`.)

`aio_write` itself does need `write_iter`, and [will return `-EINVAL` if it’s not available](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.4/source/fs/aio.c#L1563). There’s [a generic implementation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.4/source/mm/filemap.c#L3461) available which can be used in many cases, but it won’t be used as a fallback automatically.

Comment: ohh nice, in newer version if `async io read` is not implemented, will it throws error?

Comment: If you mean `aio_read` and `read_iter`, the answer is [yes](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.4/source/fs/aio.c#L1536).